# How to check if a C++ header file is correct with gcc tools?

Tags: c++, gcc, header

How can I check if the syntax of a header file is correct with gcc tools?

Comment: Write a stub program that `#include`s the header and compile it?  Without more information, this question isn't going to get a useful answer.

Comment: Umm... use it in a source file...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try compiling it with `g++`, as in `g++ -c myheader.h`. This will catch any syntax errors.

Comment: `g++ -fsyntax-only -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated -std=c++11 myheader.h`

Answer (score 19):

**`-fsyntax-only`**

Does exactly what you want:

```
echo 'int i;' > good.hpp
echo 'int i' > bad.hpp
g++ -fsyntax-only good.hpp
echo $?
# 0
g++ -fsyntax-only bad.hpp
# bad.hpp:1:5: error: expected initializer at end of input
# int i
#     ^
echo $?
# 1
g++ --version | head -n1
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
```

`man g++` says:

```
-fsyntax-only
    Check the code for syntax errors, but don't do anything beyond that.
```

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as correct as it explains exact solution for the problem, not just workaround.

Comment: Type checking is performed as well (i.e. some static semantic checking is performed beyond just lexical and syntax)

Answer (score 4):

make a cpp file which does but include the header and compile it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I usually ensure that every header is included by a source file. If, for example, a library I'm developing is header-only, I specifically write a bare-bones unit test specifically to include any stand-alone headers, and test instantiation of any templates in that header.